# how to get hour integer from python datetime.time field

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a datetime.time field that is equal to 3:00.

How can I get 3 as an integer from this object?

I have tried:

```
transaction_time = form.cleaned_data['transaction_time']
print transaction_time.hour
```

I get the error:

> 'unicode' object has no attribute 'hour'

Comment: Did you try getting a `datetime.time` first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs:

> If a Field has required=False and you pass clean() an empty value,
>   then clean() will return a normalized empty value rather than raising
>   ValidationError. For CharField, this will be a Unicode empty string.
>   For other Field classes, it might be None. (This varies from field to
>   field.)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/

So as Arun mentioned, I did string manipulation to determine the time:

```
def set_hour_for_date(customer, hour_str, transaction_date):
    meridian = hour_str[-2:]
    hour = int(hour_str[:2])
    if meridian == 'PM':
        hour = hour + 12
    relative_time = customer.time_zone.localize(datetime(
                                                        transaction_date.year, 
                                                        transaction_date.month, 
                                                        transaction_date.day, 
                                                        hour, 
                                                        0, 
                                                        0, 
                                                        294757))

    return relative_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like transaction_time is of type unicode. You can use string manipulation to get the hour part(transaction_time[0]) or typecast it to datetime and get hour.

Answer (score 0):

transaction_time is not a time object, it's unicode, so convert it first to a struct_time using **strptime**, then get the field tm_hour.

```
from time import strptime
t = strptime(form.cleaned_data['transaction_time'], '%H:%M')

print t.tm_hour
```